# displaying input data in a div JavaScript ajax (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new to javascript and ajax,and i am working in jsfiddle: my aim is to display the username and email in a list when the form is submitted.
currently when i submit the form i get this error: **{"error":"key missing: title"}**

I'm not sure what im doing wrong, Any form of assistance will be highly appreciated

Here is my code so far

```js
var Uname = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var error = document.getElementById("errors");
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var users = document.getElementById("users");

/*EMAIL VALIDATION*/
email.onkeyup =function validateEmail(){
 if(!emailReg.test(email.value)){
   error.innerHTML = "please enter a valid email address";
    error.style.color = "red";
    email.style.border = "3px solid red";
  }
  else if(emailReg.test(email.value)){
   error.innerHTML = "valid email!";
    error.style.color = "green";
    email.style.border = "3px solid green";
  }
};
/*EMAIL VALIDATION END*/

/* GET INPUT FIELD VALUES */
var username = Uname.value;
var email2 = email.value;

/* CALLBACK FUNCTION */
function callBack(){
 var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("text");
  newLi.appendChild(newContent);
}
addUser(username, email2, callBack);


function addUser(username, email, callback) {
    var response,
        success = (!!Math.round(Math.random()));
    
    if(!success){
        response = JSON.stringify({
            success: success,
            error: "Oups, something went wrong!"
        });
    } else {
        response = JSON.stringify({
            success: success,
            user: {
                username: username,
                email: email
            }
        });   
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            json: response
        },
        success: callback
    });
}
```

```html
<h2>Add a User:</h2>
<form id="add-user" method="POST" >
  <input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="name"/>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
  <button id="btn" onclick="return addUser()">add user</button>
</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
<h2>Users:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

:

Comment: Sounds like the backend is expecting a `title` key in the payload.

Comment: Thanks for the response Phix. can you help with fixing this error?

Comment: @mr.ogodo, to support Phix's answer try user: {
                `username: username,
                email: email,
                title: "your title" `
            }
OR
You need to identify what object server is expecting.

Comment: error still persists

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jknepv4/) I had to make some changes but it works

Comment: @Nilesh thanks for that is it possible to have the result display in the users <ul> and not on a new page?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, just make sure you don't wrap everything around a form. Cause when you click add user that will trigger a postback, or you can do [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

[Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/9jknepv4/73/) fiddle.

And BTW if you are using jquery you do not need to use `document.getElementById` you can just use `$("#SOMEELEMENTID")`; and you don't need  `document.createElement` just use `$("#users").append()`

And a side note you can use [this](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize a form into json.